# Resize View onClick Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm pretty new to compose and having difficulty resizing views. I have a view where I am initially hardcoding it to some size. When clicking the view I want it to expand it to fill the width to certain extent. How is this possible with in compose?

```
@Composable
fun InputBar(
   hint: String,
   onClick: () -> Unit
) {
    Card(
        onClick = { /* update view to fillMaxWidth() */ },
        modifier = Modifier
            .width(150.dp)
            .height(44.dp),
    ) {
        Row(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
            TextField(
                value = "",
                onValueChange = {

                },
                placeholder = { Text(hint) }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: check expand animation https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/animation

Comment: @Raghunandan, i have but doesnt account for resizing the view itself

Comment: Modifier has a `then` function to combine current modifier with another one, like `modifier = Modifier.height(44.dp).then(if (isCardExpanded) Modifier.fillMaxWidth() else Modifier.width(150.dp))`. Where `isCardExpanded` is Boolean state, changing in onClick

Answer (score 0):

you could achieve your by using something like this:

```
import android.util.Log
import androidx.compose.foundation.clickable
import androidx.compose.foundation.interaction.MutableInteractionSource
import androidx.compose.foundation.interaction.PressInteraction
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Row
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxWidth
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.height
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.width
import androidx.compose.material.Card
import androidx.compose.material.ExperimentalMaterialApi
import androidx.compose.material.Text
import androidx.compose.material.TextField
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.LaunchedEffect
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import kotlin.math.log

private const val TAG = "InputBar"

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterialApi::class)
@Composable
fun InputBar(
    hint: String,
    onClick: () -> Unit
) {
    var isFillMaxWidth by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    val isExpandModifier = remember(isFillMaxWidth){
        Modifier
            .height(44.dp)
            .then(
                if (isFillMaxWidth) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "InputBar: fillMaxWidth")
                    Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
                } else {
                    Log.i(TAG, "InputBar: 150")
                    Modifier.width(150.dp)
                }

            )}
    Card(
        modifier = isExpandModifier,
    ) {
        Row(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
            TextField(
                value = "",
                onValueChange = {

                },
                placeholder = { Text(hint) },
                interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }
                    .also { interactionSource ->
                        LaunchedEffect(interactionSource) {
                            interactionSource.interactions.collect {
                                if (it is PressInteraction.Release) {
                                    // works like onClick
                                    isFillMaxWidth = !isFillMaxWidth
                                    Log.i(TAG, "InputBar: onClick")
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
            )
        }
    }
}
```